# git rename/delete confusion

Tags: git, git-merge

I having one confusion about a particular git behavior:

Following are the steps and situation (the list of commands are also given later):

1. I have two branches: master and XBranch
2. There is a file src/a.txt in both of them. It's content is "Old Content"
3. In XBranch I rename src/a.txt to src/b.txt, using: `mv`, `git rm`, `git add`.
4. In master  rename the file a.txt. During commit I did `git rm src/a.txt` but forgot to do `git add src/b.txt`
   In master I do: `git rm src/a.txt` and `git commit`
5. In master, I edit the content of the file b.txt to "`New Content`
6. In master I do `git add src/b.txt` and `git commit`
7. In master I do: `git merge XBranch`

The file src/b.txt conflicts, which is perfectly understandable.
But the content is "`Old Content`". Why?

Why *not* is it something like:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
New Content
=======
Old content
>>>>>>> XBranch
```

## List of Commands:

```
sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2
$ mkdir source

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in d:/merge_temp/test/case2/.git/

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2 (master)
$ mkdir src

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2 (master)
$ vi src/a.txt

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2 (master)
$ cat src/a.txt
Old Content

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2 (master)
$ git add src/

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2 (master)
$ git commit
[master (root-commit) 148500e] added src/a.txt
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 src/a.txt

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2 (master)
$ git branch XBranch

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2 (master)
$ git checkout XBranch
Switched to branch 'XBranch'

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2 (XBranch)
$ mv src/a.txt src/b.txt

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2 (XBranch)
$ git rm src/a.txt
rm 'src/a.txt'

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2 (XBranch)
$ git add src/b.txt

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2 (XBranch)
$ git commit
[XBranch b3ff8fa] changed a.txt to b.txt in XBranch
 1 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename src/{a.txt => b.txt} (100%)

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2 (XBranch)
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2 (master)
$ mv src/a.txt src/b.txt

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2 (master)
$ git rm src/a.txt
rm 'src/a.txt'

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2 (master)
$ git commit
[master bfeaecb] removed src/a.txt
 1 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 src/a.txt

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2 (master)
$ vi src/b.txt

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2 (master)
$ cat src/b.txt
New Content

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2 (master)
$ git add src/b.txt

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2 (master)
$ git commit
[master 2361d5e] changed content of b.txt
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 src/b.txt

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2 (master)
$ git merge XBranch
CONFLICT (rename/delete): Rename src/a.txt->src/b.txt in XBranch and deleted in HEAD
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

sabya@SABYA-PC d:/merge_temp/test/case2 (master|MERGING)
$ cat src/b.txt
Old Content
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a conflict, but not about the *file* content. It is about the
***tree*** content.

- In one tree, the `case2` directory (in master), there is a *new* file `b.txt`
- in the same directory (in XBranch), there is a *renamed* file `a.txt => b.txt`

When you are resolving the conflict, you are in effect choosing one file or the
other (not one line within the file). Hence the "Old Content" in the resulting
file.

---

The OP adds in the comments:

> But then how logically is it different from the following situation:
>
> 1. I add a file `a.txt` in `master` with "Old Content" and commit it.
> 2. I add a file `a.txt` in `XBranch` with "New Content" and commit it.
> 3. I merge `XBranch` into `master`.
>      This time it is showing both contents in that file!

This time, both trees (the case2 directory in branches `master` and `XBranch`)
reference a *new* file `a.txt`: its content get merged, with conflict
resolution. Before, there was a conflict between a `a.txt`
(*renamed* as `b.txt`) and a *new* **b.txt**: both files cannot exist in the
same branch, a choice (of file, not of file content) had to be made.

> In step 4 of my question, if I do "`git rm`" and "`git add`" in a single
>   commit, it works as I expect! I fail to understand that now.
>   How can I predict when the file will have both contents?
>   When it will just have the content of `XBranch` and when will it have just the
>   content of `master`?

That means that:

- instead of merging `XBranch` (`a.txt` renamed as `b.txt`) to `master` commit
  with a new `b.txt` from step 6 (conflict of tree),
- you would merge `XBranch` (`a.txt` renamed as `b.txt`) with master from new
  step 4 (`a.txt` *also renamed* as `b.txt`): **same tree content, but different
  blob content**: conflict of lines.

---

That being said, the OP still thinks there must be a bug:

- [git mailing-list question](http://ns.spinics.net/lists/git/msg133831.html)
- [GitHub support question](http://web.archive.org/web/support.github.com/discussions/repos/3438-can-anybody-answer-this-confusion-about-git-deleterename)

---

Note: Git 2.18 (Q2 2018) changes that conflict detection report with a merge recursive.
See [commit 6e7e027](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e7e027fe5f4a8d61597a86e7f2b6087e23a759c) (19 Apr 2018) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).

> ### `merge-recursive`: avoid spurious rename/rename conflict from dir renames
>
> If a file on one side of history was renamed, and merely modified on the
>   other side, then applying a directory rename to the modified side gives us
>   a `rename/rename(1to2)` conflict.
>   We should only apply directory renames to pairs representing either adds or renames.
>
> Making this change means that a directory rename testcase that was
>   **previously reported as a `rename/delete` conflict will now be reported as a
>   `modify/delete` conflict**.

---

When a binary file gets modified and renamed on both sides of history to different locations, both files would be written to the working tree but both would have the contents from "`ours`".

This has been corrected with Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), so that the path from each side gets their original content.

See [commit 95983da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95983da6b461a4394117d4f9fcca211d7fc1403f) (13 May 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit abbd1d9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/abbd1d9ebf9033924153c7a0f0abb37e7c8e50fd), 20 May 2020)</sup>

> ### [`merge-recursive`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95983da6b461a4394117d4f9fcca211d7fc1403f): fix rename/rename(1to2) for working tree with a binary
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Chunlin Zhang</sup>
>   <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>
>
> With a rename/rename(1to2) conflict, we attempt to do a three-way merge of the file contents, so that the correct contents can be placed in the working tree at both paths.
>
> If the file is a binary, however, no content merging is possible and we should just use the original version of the file at each of the paths.

Comment: But then how logically is it different from the following situation:
1. I add a file a.txt in master with "Old Content" and commit it.
2. I add a file a.txt in XBranch with "New Content" and commit it.
3. I merge XBranch into master.

This time it is showing both contents in that file!

Comment: @Sabya: this time, both trees (the `case2` directory in branches `master` and `XBranch`) reference a *new* file `a.txt`: its content get merged, with conflict resolution. Before, there was a conflict between a **`a.txt`** (renamed as `b.txt`) and a new **`b.txt`**: both files cannot exist in the same branch, a choice (of file, not of file content) had to be made.

Comment: In step 4 of my question, if I do "git rm" and "git add" in a single commit, it works as I expect!
I fail to understand that now. How can I predict when the file will have both contents? When it will just have the content of XBranch and when will it have just the content of master?

Comment: @That means that, instead of merging `XBranch` (`a.txt` renamed as `b.txt`) to master commit with a *new* `b.txt` from step 6 (conflict of tree), you would merge `XBranch` (`a.txt` renamed as `b.txt`) with master from new step 4 (`a.txt` also renamed as `b.txt`): **same tree content, but different blob content**: conflict of lines.

Comment: I reported this to git mailing list. One person from there said this could be a bug. The content of both the files being present in this case can be an expected behavior.

Comment: @Sabya: right: http://ns.spinics.net/lists/git/msg133831.html. I stand by my original explanations. http://support.github.com/discussions/repos/3438-can-anybody-answer-this-confusion-about-git-deleterename GitHub support explanation seems reasonable too.

Comment: As this answer and its comments provide all required information, I'm marking the answer as accepted.

Comment: It'd be nice also to include in this answer how to resolve the conflict. How do I view the new content? I'm not even sure which version I'm looking at. I don't think I want to add the file, b/c I want the new content. But I can't checkout the file (to erase the changes), b/c I get a "path is unmerged" error. I definitely don't want to delete it. If I `git reset -- <path>` then there are no changes to commit, and I'm forced to `git rebase --skip`. But that just abruptly ended the rebase!! (I still had more commits to apply! They were dropped!)