# Will git cause major merge conflicts when renaming a folder?

Tags: git, version-control, merge-conflict-resolution

Consider a folder structure on a branch `dev` like this:

```
~root/folderX/fileA
~root/folderY/fileB
~root/..
..
```

What happens if I rename and push a rename of the `root` folder into the branch?

Does that mean that all the current pull requests will fail to merge or any changes done locally by other developers that aren't yet pushed will result in merge conflicts? (Because they changed/updated files in the `root` folder which now doesn't exist since it's been renamed)

I just want to make sure before I go ahead and rename a major folder, in how Git handles this. Also, what's the best way to handle this situation?

Comment: you can easily check if merges still work by simply creating a private local branch, do the rename there and then try to merge anything into that local branch that is still based on the old master layout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git merge branches with different directory structures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582605/git-merge-branches-with-different-directory-structures)