# Git CONFLICT (rename/delete) Fix

Tags: laravel, git, github, bitbucket

Hi  I have a conflict `CONFLICT (rename/delete)` in my repo..  yesterday I have deleted a  migration file from  master branch which is not present either any of other feature branches, but when I try to push my develop it returns the `CONFLICT (rename/delete)` error .. the conflict isn't in the content.. because it is a separate file.. why this happening and how to resolve this?

```
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 bb4104c5ebfc8c50640b11ee983a229536f12bbe and renamed to database/migrations/2021_03_12_082940_add_exercise_group_id_exercise_table.php in HEAD. Version HEAD of database/migrations/2021_03_12_082940_add_exercise_group_id_exercise_table.php left in 
tree.
```

Answer (score 1):

> why this happening ...

It's happening because there is a conflict between a rename and a delete.

This answer is not very helpful, but it is as helpful as *possible*, given what you have told us.  In particular, one of the things you did tell us is *wrong:*

> when I try to push my develop it returns the `CONFLICT (rename/delete)` error

`git push` never does a merge, and the conflict occurs on a merge.  Your output here:

> ```
>  * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
> ```

is from `git pull`, not `git push`.  The pull command means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command* and the default second Git command is usually `git merge`, so that part makes sense: you ran `git pull`, which ran `git merge`, which encountered this rename/delete conflict.

Perhaps you mean to ask "what are some examples that cause a rename/delete conflict", which is answerable: see, e.g., [git rename/delete confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3100032/1256452).

> ... and how to resolve this?

You, as the (smart) human programmer, must decide what the correct set of files in the final merge is to be.  Git is a dumb simple program, following some simple rules; those rules have hit a problem.

See, e.g., [Git - what does CONFLICT (rename/delete) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39312133/1256452) and [git - merge conflict when local is deleted but file exists in remote](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4319486/1256452) and [How do I fix a merge conflict due to removal of a file in a branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1380670/1256452)  Some of these are about modify/delete conflicts, rather than rename/delete, but in the end the process is always the same:

- Git tried to merge, using its dumb and simple rules.
- These dumb and simple rules failed.  Git stopped in the middle of the merge.
- Your job is now to fix the mess Git left behind.  Figure out which files *should* exist and what should be *in those files*.

Once you have the right set of files, with the right contents, use `git add` and/or `git rm` to tell Git *these are the right files*.  Then run `git merge --continue` to finish the in-progress merge.